# linux linker: '-lpng' inhibits '-lz'?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

On ubuntu-13.04, I got an error when building an executable from shared libraries, using GCC-4.7.3 provided by the linux distribution.

I guess the problem is between libpng and zlib (the former uses the latter), but I don't know why.

First, my command is:

```
$ gfortran -o test_muesli_config_fml test_muesli_config_fml.o -fopenmp 
-Wl,--rpath,/usr/local/lib/muesli /usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so -lstdc++
-Wl,--rpath,/usr/lib /usr/lib/liblapack.so -Wl,--rpath,/usr/lib /usr/lib/libblas.so
-lpng -lz -lpthread -lreadline -lhistory
```

which gives the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: undefined reference to `gzwrite'
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: undefined reference to `gzopen'
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: undefined reference to `gzclose'
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: undefined reference to `gzread'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But note that `-lz` is present. After that, I added the linker option `--trace-symbol=` in order to get more information:

```
$ gfortran -o test_muesli_config_fml test_muesli_config_fml.o -fopenmp 
-Wl,--rpath,/usr/local/lib/muesli /usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so -lstdc++
-Wl,--rpath,/usr/lib /usr/lib/liblapack.so -Wl,--rpath,/usr/lib /usr/lib/libblas.so
-lpng -lz -lpthread -lreadline -lhistory -Wl,--trace-symbol=gzwrite
```

which in turn gives the results:

```
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: reference to gzwrite
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so: definition of gzwrite
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: undefined reference to `gzwrite'
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: undefined reference to `gzopen'
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: undefined reference to `gzclose'
/usr/local/lib/muesli/libfml.so: undefined reference to `gzread'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

so, `gzwrite` is found in `libz.so` but the linker don't use it!

By chance, I thought to remove the `-lpng` option (actually, the libpng library is not used) and my problem is solved! Why?

Secondly, I compile my whole code with another version of GCC-4.7.3 (compiled by myself -- I am used to test many versions of the compiler), and the error didn't occur, even using both `-lpng` and `-lz`!

Any idea?

In addition, a different try with another program (which USE libpng) leads to a successful build.

**Edited on 2013-10-08**

I'm pretty sure now that it is a bug in ubuntu-13.04: I've tried two other linux distros (Fedora 16 -- Ubuntu-10.04) and the linker behavior is standard, not as described above in the first part of my message.

I plan to report this problem on ubuntu community. Regards.

**Edited on 2013-10-09**

The bug has been reported to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1237270

Comment: What if you reverse the order of -lpng and -lz in the linker command line? Although I thought order matters only for static libs...

Comment: I have already tried many things, as multiple -lz occurences: gives nothing!

Comment: Could it be that (Ubuntu's) libpng defines these symbols in a way that makes them unusable for further resolving, causing libz to be ignored (the symbols are already acquired) but not letting them be used? I know this sounds like total crazy-talk, but it's what I'm seeing in this here. I'm guessing `nm` or `objdump` on libpng and comparing the libz symbols to the proper libz might shed some more light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible fixes (until ubuntu doesn't repair itself):

1. Try to compile in `libpng.a` and `libz.a` as a static library (it can be only a temporary solution, because static libs are evil in most cases).
2. Recompile libpng from the original source, and compile `libz.a` as static herein.